# Spring boot com erro ao conectar no mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, spring-boot

Criei um projeto de teste pelo Spring Tool Suite para criar um servidor REST que vai se conectar com um banco de dados mysql local, quando dou start na aplicação ele da erro ao tentar conectar com o mysql: **java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

Acho estranho que ele não tentou com o usuário root que configurei no projeto.

O application.properties esta assim:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=mysql

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/users
spring.datasource.data-username=root
spring.datasource.data-password=12345
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

E o pom.xml esta assim:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

No banco de dados eu executei o seguinte comando:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

Depois de executar eu parei e iniciei o mysql.

Pelo que entendo, esse comando da acesso ao root em todas as tabelas e de qualquer lugar.

Acho estranho que no erro aparece ''@'localhost' em vez de 'root'@'localhost', parece que nem pegou a configuração para acesso ao banco.

Sera que é a config. da conexão que esta errada, o pom.xml ou o banco ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode enviar a árvore de diretórios que está sendo utilizada?
Como está fazendo para executar?
O erro "(using password: NO)" significa que o Spring Boot não conseguiu refletir às configurações do seu arquivo de Properties.

Confira se o diretório do arquivo de Properties é /projeto/src/main/resources/application.properties

Além disso as suas properties não estão corretas. Utilize:
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 12345

Exemplo: https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate/src/main/resources/application.properties

:D

Comment: O problema era na configuração:
spring.datasource.username = root 
spring.datasource.password = 12345
Coloquei isso e resolveu! Obrigado!